# What's the usage of a a def in a function?

Tags: python, function, python-3.6

Just reading the Python doc's in particular [this](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/operator.html?highlight=getter#operator.attrgetter) page, in regards to attrgetter and itemgetter.

I'm struggling to understand the usage of the usage of `def` and `return` in the code examples. **Not** the usage of those functions.

It seems like a `lamdba`, but I don't know how to interpret it.

**EDIT**

---

I think it just clicked. The attrgetter is like a constructor for the resolve_attr function? This was a little confusing, as i'd normally expect the code for a def to be between the `def` and the `return`. The code on the return is like a lambda. To add to the confusion the arg `ojb` is the argument passed to the returned object. Arhhhhh.....

---

What do i need to know for this to make sense?

This is the code example I'm referring to:

```
   def attrgetter(*items):
    if any(not isinstance(item, str) for item in items):
        raise TypeError('attribute name must be a string')
    if len(items) == 1:
        attr = items[0]
        def g(obj): #What is this
            return resolve_attr(obj, attr)
    else:
        def g(obj):#And this?
            return tuple(resolve_attr(obj, attr) for attr in items)
    return g

def resolve_attr(obj, attr):
    for name in attr.split("."):
        obj = getattr(obj, name)
    return obj
```

Comment: Look up "higher order functions". These are functions that either take functions as arguments and/or return functions. This is an example of a function factory, a common pattern.

Comment: See [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function). The other idea you should be aware of is that Python has [first class functions](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function). These ideas are common to the [functional programming paradigm](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming)

Comment: yeah ta, reading right now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`def` is the keyword to define a function.

These are just functions defined inside another function  `attrgetter()`

That's why you have multiple `return` inside `attrgetter()`

`g` looks like `lambda` because `attrgetter()`  returns a function, and not the result directly.

`g` could be replaced by a lambda declaration indeed.

Answer (score 3):

In Python, functions are just like normal object. You can pass them around, and (as in the example above) return them from other functions.

The example function, returns another function as its return value. It does so by defining a function (that's the `def g(ojb):` line) and then simply returning it.

You can do this, because in Python - a function is just like any other object.